# Android emulator in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a problem with my emulator - it's starting in landscape mode.

The emulator is in portrait but the display screen is getting started in landscape position.

Here's a screenshot to show what I mean.

How can I fix this?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: That is wired have no idea why that happens beside. I'm using the [This emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/) and it start 10 times faster then the Android Virtual device manager emulator.

Comment: mind posting the emulators config.ini file. You can get this file from the folder where you created the emulator. Open AVD manager and highlight the emulator and it would list the avd folder.